# Looping over matrix elements more efficiently in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I am writing some matlab code and have written an algorithm that works but I don't think its particularly efficient. Since I am trying to improve my programming skills I would like to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

I have a (reasonably large ~ E07) matrix of values which are unordered, but fall within the range [-100, 100]. I want to create a second matrix based on the first, by using the following rules:

1. If the value of the point is > 70, then the value of the point should be set to 70.
2. If the value of the point is < -70, then the value of the point should be set to -70.
3. All other values should be rounded to the nearest multiple of 5.

Here is what I am currently doing:

```
data = 100*(-1+2*rand(1,10000000)); % create random dataset for stackoverflow
new_data = zeros(1,length(data));

for i = 1:length(data)
    if (data(i) > 70)
        new_data(i) = 70;
    elseif (data(i) < -70)
        new_data(i) = -70;
    else
        new_data(i) = round(data(i)/5.0)*5.0;
    end
end
```

Is there a more efficient method? I think there should be a way to do this using logical indexes but those are a new discovery for me...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need a loop at all:

```
data = 100*(-1+2*rand(1,10000000)); % create random dataset for stackoverflow
new_data = zeros(1,length(data)); % note that this memory allocation is not necessary at this point

new_data = round(data/5.0)*5.0;
new_data(data>70) = 70;    
new_data(data<-70) = -70;
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I wanted! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Even easier is to use max and min. Do it in one simple line.

```
new_data = round(5*max(-70,min(70,data)))/5;
```

Comment: Nice. I prefer the readability of @H.Muster 's answer, but I think this one liner is more computationally efficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The two answers by H.Muster and woodchips are of course the way to do it, but there still are small improvements to be found. If you are after performance you might want to exploit specifics of your problem. For example, your **output** data is integers `-100 <= x <= 100`. This obviously qualifies for 8-bit signed integer data type. This code (note explicit cast to `int8` from arbitrary double precision data)

```
% your double precision input data
data = 100*(-1+2*rand(1,10000000));

% cast to int8 - matlab does usual round here
data = int8(data);
new_data = 5*(max(-70,min(70,data))/5);
```

is the fastest for two reasons:

- 1 data element takes 1 byte, not 8. Memory bandwidth is a limiting factor here, so you get a lot of improvement
- round is no longer necessary

Here are some timings from the codes of H.Muster, woodchips, and my small modification:

```
H.Muster    Elapsed time is 0.235885 seconds.
woodchips   Elapsed time is 0.167659 seconds.
my code     Elapsed time is 0.023061 seconds.
```

The difference is quite striking. Although MATLAB uses doubles everywhere, you should try to use integer data types when possible..

**Edit** This works because of how matlab implements integer arithmetic. Differently than in C, a cast of double to int implies a `round` operation:

```
a = 0.1;
int8(a)

ans =
  0

a = 0.9;
int8(a)

ans =
  1
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. The data I'm actually working on is not an integer set though---they're all doubles.

Comment: @FakeDIY I was clearly not clear enough :) Run the code for the same double input data as the others. It gives the same results. Your input data does not need to be integers - the main thing is that your **output** data is. I use an explicit cast to `uint8`, which does initial rounding and is part of the method. In short, for your generated test data all methods yield the same result.

Comment: Ahh, got you. Data types is not something I know a lot about---thats a really nice method though. :-)